# a question about the CnosDB create statement

Tags: cnosdb

cnosdb version：ef1b5d0dcc9d3db0858e8d850a89b07b3c839a5f
I find that this statement can be executed
[image]

CnosDB SQL:create table `test1(col bigint);`
The error message is displayed in the image above：

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009", "error_message": "sql parse err: Expected CODEC or ',' found:)"}
```

Expected the problem to be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

create table test1(col bigint,);